# SPRING-XD - Getting Error:" xd-admin dead but pid file exists"

Tags: spring, hadoop, spring-xd

**We have small pivotal hadoop cluster.In that cluster, We are using spring-xd as data ingestion tool.**

**Tried:**

When following command executed from spring xd-admin machine:

```
[root@host ~]# service spring-xd-admin status 
xd-admin dead but pid file exists
```

**Outcome:**

Both spring-xd-admin and container stopped responding. 
Hence,cluster data pipeline has been stopped completely.

**Advance Thanks For Help ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the service crashed and left a pid file behind. You would have to remove the pid file manually. Look for a file named `xd-admin.pid` in the `/var/run/` directory.

Comment: Thanks for reply. We executed following command. on spring-xd-admin machine.
>rm -f /var/run/xd-admin.pid. But error remains same. Adding one more information Our spring-xd install is via ambari.

Comment: If you have an Ambari install of Spring XD then the processes are all controlled by Ambari so the service script won't work for checking status. You need to use the Ambari UI or the Ambari REST interface https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=41812517

Comment: Being novice for Ambari UI,It is Very useful information.Thanks a ton.